# Java replace function

Tags: java

In my current work, I have to write a replace function. A replace function, which take file path ( e.g., `/sim/device` ) as input and generates  output - `sim.device`.

In java, I have tried with `replace("/", ".")`. But, this function produce output `.sim.device`.

My question is that  " In Java, is there any function, which solves my purpose or should I write function myself ?"  you could suggest efficient java code also.

Comment: Take the substring from 1 of the initial result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to ignore the first character you can use substring.

```
String text = "/my/sim/device";
String text2 = text.substring(1).replace('/','.');
System.out.println(text2);
```

prints

```
my.sim.device
```

Answer (score 8):

```
String s = "/sim/device";
System.out.println( s.replace("/", ".").substring( 1));
```

Answer (score 3):

Using this one have try:

```
replaceAll("(?<=\\S+)/", ".").substring(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The replace function replaces all instances of the first string with the second string.  In this case...

```
Input:  /sim/device
Output: .sim.device
```

If you'll take note, every location where you have a '/', you now have a '.'.  If your goal is to remove the first character of the string, take a look at the String.substring() method.

Oh, and as a general recommendation, read through the Java Tutorial.  It's free, available on the web from Oracle, and provides an excellent explanation of how to use Java.  And it would have answered this question for you, already, had you completed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Not a single function call, but solves your need.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String path = "/sim/device";
    System.out.println(path.replace("/",".").substring(1,path.length()));

}
```